# Describe a data structure to track visitors

Tags: data-structures

> Given $n$ cities, describe a data structure which supports the following functions:
>
> Init$(n)$ - initializes the data structure in $O(1)$
>
> Visit$(j,i)$ - adds "citizen from city $j$ would like to visit city $i$" in $O(1)$
>
> Favorite($k$) - prints the $k$ most favorite cities in descending order in $O(k)$ (ignore ambiguity such as 2 cities with same amount)

I can't find how to do the last one in $O(k)$, hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise in the description of the data structure operations? What's the role of $j$ in Visit($j$, $i$)? What do you mean by "the $k$ most favorite cities"? Is it legal to perform Visit($j$, $i$) more than once for the same pair $(j,i)$?

Comment: @Steven it is just a representation for a city, but I see your point. 
There are actually more functions which I didn't include due to irrelevance to my question, which use this information. If you think it would help i'll add them.

Comment: @Steven
Also, I mean the cities which have the biggest amount of people who want to visit them, and yes it is legal.

Comment: Can you confirm that the time needed by Init$(n)$ must be $O(1)$ (and not $O(n)$)? The problem is easy to solve if you can spend $O(n)$ time.

Comment: @Steven
It's $O(1)$. Note an array can be initialized in O(1): https://thunderwiring.wordpress.com/2015/04/04/initializing-array-in-o1-c/#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20initialize%20an,time%2C%20whereas%20n%20%3D%20array_size.

Comment: Then the problem is easily solved :D I'll write up the solution in an answer (assuming an uninitialized array of $n$ elements can be allocated in $O(1)$ time)

Comment: @Steven Thank you, much appreciated. If you could write a little hint as an intro to the answer it would be great.

Comment: @paxtibimarce fyi, The provided implementation of an array with $O(1)$ initialization is wrong. The following program: "Array<int> arr = Array<int>(10); arr[5] = 42; std::cout << arr[5];" will return GARBAGE for arr[5].

Comment: @VladislavBezhentsev Could be, I didn't look at this very thoroughly to be honest. My point was just that it is possible, it can be used as a black box here.

Comment: @paxtibimarce, My point is that the whole idea described in that article is wrong. And generally $O(1)$ initialization for an array is impossible (even if we do not account for allocation time). But may be Steven's algorithm won't be based on an array initialization and will use a hash table (or something) instead. Let's see...

Comment: @VladislavBezhentsev. My solution relies on allocating an uninitialized array in $O(1)$ time and on being able to detect uninitialized values. We cannot use hash-tables since they don't support lookups in $O(1)$ **worst-case** time.

Comment: @VladislavBezhentsev. It seems to me that the **idea** of the approach described [here](https://thunderwiring.wordpress.com/2015/04/04/initializing-array-in-o1-c/#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20initialize%20an,time%2C%20whereas%20n%20%3D%20array_size) works. But their write-up has some errors (and I haven't checked the code).

Comment: @Steven, It seems to me that their check for $index \leq top$ just makes no sense. $top$ counts for a number of write operations to an array, $index$ is an index of an element we are currently interested in. Why should they relate to each other in some particular way?

Comment: @VladislavBezhentsev, that's exactly the error I was referring to. I think that the check should be sideArray[index] $<$ top. If this test fails then sideArray[index] 
 is uninitialized and Array[index] must also be uninitialized. If this test succeeds then it is safe to check stackArray[sideArray[index]]. Since this is definitely an initialized value on the stack and the stack contains only indices of initialized locations of Array, then we know that if stackArray[sideArray[index]]=index Array[index] must be initialized. The converse is also true by construction.

Comment: @Steven, Yes, thanks, now I see.

Comment: Please credit the original source of all copied material.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: Please don't provide clarifications in the comments (e.g., the definition of most favorite cities).   Instead, [edit] your question to include all relevant information and to read well for someone who encounters it for the first time; and then flag as 'no longer needed' those comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to keep a sorted list of non-empty "buckets". Each bucket $v$ is associated to a certain number $n_v$ of people that wish to visit some city and contains all the cities $c$ that wish to be visited by exactly $n_v$ people.

By keeping a suitable set of pointers cities can be moved from one bucket to the next in constant time. To perform a Favorite($k$) operation it suffices to look at the "last" buckets in the sorted list.

---

The data structure consists of:

- A doubly-linked list $L$. Each node $v$ of $L$ is associated to an integer $\eta_v$ and to a (pointer) to an inner list $\ell_v$ of cities $c$ such that exactly $\eta_v > 0$ people want to visit $c$. The integers $\eta_v$ are appear in increasing order when traversing $L$.
- An array $N$ of $n$ elements. The $i$-th element $n_i$ of $N$, if initialized, is the number of people that want to visit the $i$-th city.
- An array $P^L$ of $n$ elements. The $i$-th element $p^L_i$ of $P^L$, if initialized, is a pointer to the node $v$ of $L$ such that $\eta_v = n_i$.
- An array $P^\ell$ of $n$ elements. The $i$-th element $p^\ell_i$ of $P^\ell$, if initialized, is a pointer to the node containing the $i$-th city in the list $\ell_v$, where $v$ is the node of $L$ pointed by $p^L_i$.

**Init$(n)$**:

- Create an empty list $L$. Allocate (but do not inizialize) the arrays $N$, $P^L$, and $P^\ell$ in $O(1)$ time.

**Visit$(\cdot,i)$**:

- If $n_i$ is initialized, delete (in constant time) the node pointed by $p^\ell_i$ from the list $\ell_v$ where $v$ is the node of $L$ pointed by $p^L_i$. If $\ell_v$ is empty, delete $v$ from $L$.  Increment $n_i$.
- Otherwise, if $n_i$ is not initialized, set $\eta_i=1$.
- Find the node $v'$ of $L$ such that such that $\eta_{v'}=n_i$, if it exists. Notice that $v'$ can only be the node of $L$ following (the possibly just deleted) node $p^L_i$ in $L$.
- If $v'$ did not exists, then create it (in constant time).
- Add city $i$ to a new node $z$ of $\ell_{v'}$.
- Make $p^L_i$ point to $v'$.
- Make $p^\ell_i$ point to $z$.

**Favorite$(k)$**:

- Let $v$ be last node of $L$.
- While $k>0$ and $v$ exists:

  - Let $x$ be a pointer to the first node of $\ell_v$
  - While $k > 0$ and $x$ exists:

    - Return the city stored in $x$.
    - Set $x$ to the vertex following $x$ in $\ell_v$ (possibly none).
    - Decrement $k$
  - Set $v$ to the vertex preceding $v$ in $L$ (possibly none).

Comment: I think you confused $p_i^{\ell}$ and $p_i^L$ at the end of the visit explanation?
I think I understand your design, I'll be sure to accept this answer later.

Comment: Can you point me to the specific line where the mistake is? (I can't seem to find it)

Comment: Never mind my bad

Comment: It seems right to me, since $v'$ is a node in $L$, and therefore it should be pointed to by the pointer $p_i^L$ while $z$ is a node in the list $\ell_{v'}$ therefore it should be pointed to by the pointer to the inner list $p_i^|ell$.

Comment: Btw, how do we access the last node of $L$?

Comment: @paxtibimarce, $L$ is a doubly-linked list and you can keep pointers both to the first and last nodes of $L$ (and traverse $L$ in either direction).